# how to create factory that passes override through associations

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :reminders
end

class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user
end

factory :user do
  account
end

factory :reminder do
 account
 user
end
```

How do I modify the `:reminder` factory so that I can pass in an account and that account will be used for both the Reminder as well as the User?

```
r = FactoryBot.create(:reminder, account: Account.last)
r.account.id == r.user.account.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a block to factory attribute definitions if the default does not suit you. In the current case, you want to make sure that the account and user match.

```
factory :reminder do
  account
  user { build(:user, account: account) }
end
```

This will ensure that the same account is used for the user if the factory needs to build the user. This will cover your requirement. However, there is another case that is not covered. If you pass in a user, but no account, then a new account will be built and the accounts will not match. Checking for a given user can mitigate this.

`@overrides` has the attributes that are passed in.

```
factory :reminder do
  account { @overrides[:user]&.account || build(:account) }
  user { build(:user, account: account) }
end
```

Now if only user or only account is passed into the factory, then the resulting reminder will have accounts matching.

Answer (score -1):

Try `FactoryBot.build` it will build models, with defined associations, but those should be replaced later when you assign them to account on the last line:

```
r = FactoryBot.build(:reminder)
u = FactoryBot.build(:user)
a = FactoryBot.create(:account, users: [u], reminders: [r])
```